# Concatenating dataframe that have different number of rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df = df[['A', 'B', 'C']] with 3 columns and 2000 rows

Then I have another set of data with only 200 rows

How can I add this into df['D'] such that this 200 rows will only appear as the tail of the 2000 rows?
So that from row 0-1800 for df['D'] it will be NaN and then 1801 to 2000 will be the values

Been trying various ways without success... thank you

```
data with 200 rows in this format
     [[ 0.43628979]
     [ 0.43454027]
     [ 0.43552566]
     [ 0.43542767]
     [ 0.43331838]
    ...
```

Comment: `"..Been trying various ways without success.."` : you should post some of your attempts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with changing `index` by last index values of `df1`:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(20,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
print (df1)
    A  B  C
0   8  8  3
1   7  7  0
2   4  2  5
3   2  2  2
4   1  0  8
5   4  0  9
6   6  2  4
7   1  5  3
8   4  4  3
9   7  1  1
10  7  7  0
11  2  9  9
12  3  2  5
13  8  1  0
14  7  6  2
15  0  8  2
16  5  1  8
17  1  5  4
18  2  8  3
19  5  0  9

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(2,5)), columns=list('werty'))
print (df2)
   w  e  r  t  y
0  3  6  3  4  7
1  6  3  9  0  4
```

---

```
df2.index = df1.index[-len(df2.index):]
df = df1.join(df2)
print (df)
    A  B  C    w    e    r    t    y
0   8  8  3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   7  7  0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   4  2  5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   2  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   1  0  8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   4  0  9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6   6  2  4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7   1  5  3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8   4  4  3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9   7  1  1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
10  7  7  0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11  2  9  9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
12  3  2  5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
13  8  1  0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
14  7  6  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
15  0  8  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
16  5  1  8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
17  1  5  4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
18  2  8  3  3.0  6.0  3.0  4.0  7.0
19  5  0  9  6.0  3.0  9.0  0.0  4.0
```